# weird problem with cfdirectory on ubuntu accessing smbfs on windows

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, coldfusion, permissions

Strange problem.  We use a cf web server to access NAS.  We have tested this issue to the nines and can't figure out the cause.

The problem: We get empty result sets doing a cfdirectory on the share to a known directory with the correct casing.  However, we can ls from the cf server as the cf user and see everything without permission errors.

Tests we've tried:

1. Making a test file to be user the path we are testing is correct - fail.
2. Doing a directory listing from python - works.
3. Doing a CFFILE read and write from the offending web server to the directory in question - works.
4. Doing a CFDIRECTORY on a local directory - works.
5. Doing *ls -la* on the directory sudo'd to cfuser - works.
6. Doing *ls -la* as root on the directory - works.
7. Changing cf user permissions to root and retrying CFDIRECTORY - fail.
8. Changing mount to mount as root user and retrying CFDIRECTORY - fail.
9. chown-ing the files and the parent dir and retrying CFDIRECTORY - fail.

Comment: What user is the cf service running under, and what user is the mount done under? Oh, and what are the mount parameters, are you using allow_other ?

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of a couple of things. First, make sure your case is correct since filesystem reads are case-sensitive in CF in Linux.

Secondly, I have not had much luck reading directly to SMB from CF. What has worked for me in the past is mounting a drive using SMB Fuse as a normal mount point and making sure the owner/group matches the CF user.